# Multiple exceptions in a function

Tags: python-3.x

I am returning to programming after a 34 year hiatus, but working on the same "first problem": generating D&D / DCC RPG characters. More specifically I am focusing on generating ability scores. For the moment I want to allow inputting of the 6 scores when running the script, and I want to be prompted for how many d6 I want to roll.

Never mind that I'm miles from the features I want, or that my code is inelegant, or the python features I'm using are inconsistent. I want to use what I've learned and only introduce new concepts as quickly as I can digest them.

I want to include exceptions when the user enters a non-integer, or a number of dice < 3. The first works, but the second exception does not. There is no error message though. It just wants to roll 2d6.

I've tried all manner of syntax or the second exception. I'm just not getting it:

```
from sys import argv
from random import randint

script, ability1, ability2, ability3, ability4, ability5, ability6 = argv

def inputDice(message):
    while True:
        try:
            dice = int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print("This is not a whole number; I can't roll fractional dice.")
            continue
        except(dice < 3):
            print("3d6 is the minimum number of dice.")
            continue
        else:
            return dice
            break


dice = inputDice("How many d6s do you want to roll?: ")
print(f"OK, we're rolling {dice}d6...")
```

Comment: I think you've mixed up what `except` and `raise` do

Comment: I can indeed use raise, and I think it's doing what it's supposed to, but it's not what I want. 

The except ValueError prompts the user to re-input the number of dice. Whereas the raise Exception breaks the script entirely and drops me back to the python shell. 

Ideally I'd get the same behavior if the user inputs an integer <3. 

Oh, and I was not confusing except and raise. Rather, I just learned raise existed, because you mentioned it :-)

Comment: Got it working :-):

def inputDice(message):
    while True:
        try:
            dice = int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print("This is not a whole number; I can't roll fractional dice.")
            continue
        if dice < 3:
            print("3d6 is the minimum number of dice.")
            continue
        else:
            return dice
            break